# does not work request

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

What am I doing wrong in my query?
thank you in advance for your help

new -  not work

```
$query  = "SELECT * "; 
$query .= "FROM photographs "; 
$query .= "WHERE `caption` LIKE '%".$query."%' ";
    $query .= "OR `caption2` LIKE '%".$query."%' ";
//$query .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
$query .= "ORDER BY $order_by LIMIT $start, $display ";     
$result = mysqli_query ($connection, $query);
```

old query - work

```
//$query = ("SELECT * FROM photographs WHERE (`caption` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`caption2` LIKE '%".$query."%')");
//$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Comment: Maybe it wasn't such a good idea to reuse the variable. I also see that you don't use query parameters. I just hope you have sanitized your input. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: echo the $query value before passing it to mysqli_query function , and take the output and try it on any mysql client that you use such as phpMyAdmin ,and monitor the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LIKE '%".$query."%' ";
```

should be replaced with

```
LIKE '%".$yourTerm."%' ";
```

where $yourTerm is what you are trying to search in your database

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting the `$query` variable with parts of your query. :-)